# My Views are only 320px across and I get poor resolution images on iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit, retina-display

I have a big problem that is causing all sorts of complications. I want to make native-resolution graphics for my iPhone 5 app using the 326ppi Retina Display quality graphics. However, all of my Views seem to be defaulting at 320px width! So the only option I've been able to find is to make my graphics much larger, and then use the 'redraw' graphics option to make the graphics look somewhat nice.

However, I would much rather just use pixel-for-pixel native resolution images. What can I do to get xcode to show my views with retina display resolutions? I am using the latest xcode and programming for iOS 6.1

Thanks!

Comment: This question is not really related to Xcode, per-se. You just happen to be using that IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UIKit views are measured in points:

```
(CGSize){width, height}
```

. . where width and height are measured in points. On an iPhone 3GS (normal display), this gives the following widths:

```
(CGSize){320, 480} //screen resolution is 320x480
```

On an iPhone 4:

```
(CGSize){320, 480} //screen resolution is 640x960
```

. . ie - exactly the same. To draw a pixel at position {1,1} on an iPhone 4, the point would be:

```
(CGPoint}{0.5, 0.5}
```

Since the resolution on a retina display is exactly double, it makes drawing very easy between devices. UIKit will work out what pixel to set, given the hardware, when you supply floating point numbers. (Similar to the way OpenGL works). . . . it gets a little more complicated when supported 3.5 vs 4 inch screens.

*For image assets, just name the resources as follows:*

- myResource.png - regular
- myResource@2x.png - retina display
- myResource-568@2x.png - retina display, especially for 4 inch screen. (Eg backgrounds, etc).

Comment: I see. So what should I do for images I use for things like button backgrounds? If the button is 100px by 200px, and I want to make a native resolution retina display graphic, I choose exactly 100px by 200px in photoshop, and it comes out looking like crap (since it is the number of pixels for non-retina dislpay). Are you saying I should create a file called myButtonImaeg@2x.png that is twice the dimensions of the 100x200 button I'm using now, and that ios will smartly choose the correct one?

Comment: Oh man, I just tried your suggestions, and for the first time I finally see native resolution, beautiful, crisp graphics... Thanks so much man...